# How do I resolve a SQL ParseError in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-sql, amazon-sagemaker

I'm a new-bee to PySpark and AWS Sagemaker using Jupyter Notebook. I do know how to write SQL statements to answer my questions. This code piece is supposed to:
1. Extract available methods of death dispositions in my dataset (CDC Death Data -in CSV) by year
2. Count the frequency for each disposition by year

I was able to run the SQL statement on the same dataset in a MySQL database. But once I added the query to my PySpark code, I got a `ParseError` Please, see the error below.

How would I go about resolving this error? and if I want to create a graph/plot with the output, how would I go about it?
THANKS

```
df.registerTempTable("data")
methods = sqlContext.sql("\
    SELECT current_data_year AS Year, \
        CASE method_of_disposition \
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cremation' \
            WHEN 'B' THEN 'Burial' \
            WHEN 'D' THEN 'D' \
            WHEN 'E' THEN 'E' \
            WHEN 'O' THEN 'O' \
            WHEN 'R' THEN 'R' \
            WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unknown' \
            END AS 'Method of Disposition', \
        COUNT(method_of_disposition) AS Count \
        FROM data \
        GROUP BY current_data_year, method_of_disposition\
    ").show()
```

MY NEW OUTPUT

```
+----+-------------------+-------+
|Year|MethodofDisposition|  Count|
+----+-------------------+-------+
|   0|               null|     10|
|2005|              Other|   2199|
|2005|           Donation|   4795|
|2005|                  E|  21247|
|2005|     RemovedFromUSA|  31954|
|2005|          Cremation| 350018|
|2005|             Burial| 553202|
|2005|            Unknown|1489091|
|2006|              Other|   2252|
|2006|           Donation|   6883|
|2006|                  E|  23412|
|2006|     RemovedFromUSA|  40870|
|2006|          Cremation| 423282|
|2006|             Burial| 667169|
|2006|            Unknown|1266857|
|2007|              Other|   3119|
|2007|           Donation|   8719|
|2007|                  E|  26139|
|2007|     RemovedFromUSA|  41411|
|2007|          Cremation| 472220|
|2007|             Burial| 725666|
|2007|            Unknown|1151069|
|2008|              Other|   5511|
|2008|           Donation|  10981|
|2008|                  E|  31913|
|2008|     RemovedFromUSA|  44713|
|2008|          Cremation| 579827|
|2008|             Burial| 866384|
|2008|            Unknown| 937482|
|2009|              Other|   3688|
|2009|           Donation|  12011|
|2009|                  E|  30344|
|2009|     RemovedFromUSA|  45451|
|2009|          Cremation| 599202|
|2009|             Burial| 802305|
|2009|            Unknown| 948218|
|2010|              Other|   3782|
|2010|           Donation|  15208|
|2010|                  E|  32807|
|2010|     RemovedFromUSA|  47899|
|2010|          Cremation| 706224|
|2010|            Unknown| 760192|
|2010|             Burial| 906430|
|2011|              Other|   5169|
|2011|           Donation|  17450|
|2011|                  E|  33847|
|2011|     RemovedFromUSA|  47199|
|2011|            Unknown| 685325|
|2011|          Cremation| 780480|
|2011|             Burial| 950372|
|2012|              Other|   6649|
|2012|           Donation|  20790|
|2012|                  E|  35110|
|2012|     RemovedFromUSA|  52896|
|2012|            Unknown| 440569|
|2012|          Cremation| 898222|
|2012|             Burial|1093628|
|2013|              Other|   6962|
|2013|           Donation|  21653|
|2013|                  E|  36949|
|2013|     RemovedFromUSA|  53678|
|2013|            Unknown| 395080|
|2013|          Cremation| 973768|
|2013|             Burial|1113362|
|2014|              Other|   7871|
|2014|           Donation|  24004|
|2014|                  E|  39321|
|2014|     RemovedFromUSA|  59884|
|2014|            Unknown| 242963|
|2014|          Cremation|1094292|
|2014|             Burial|1162836|
|2015|              Other|  11729|
|2015|           Donation|  27870|
|2015|                  E|  40880|
|2015|     RemovedFromUSA|  71744|
|2015|            Unknown|  74050|
|2015|          Cremation|1244297|
|2015|             Burial|1247628|
+----+-------------------+-------+
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input ''Method of Disposition'' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 213)

== SQL ==
SELECT current_data_year AS Year, CASE method_of_disposition WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cremation' WHEN 'B' THEN 'Burial' WHEN 'D' THEN 'D' WHEN 'E' THEN 'E' WHEN 'O' THEN 'O' WHEN 'R' THEN 'R' WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unknown' END AS 'Method of Disposition', COUNT(method_of_disposition) AS Count FROM data GROUP BY current_data_year, method_of_disposition
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:632)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f99c8a5b941c> in <module>()
      1 #Grouping and counting Cremation vs Burial by Year
      2 df.registerTempTable("data")
----> 3 sqlContext.sql("SELECT current_data_year AS Year, CASE method_of_disposition WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cremation' WHEN 'B' THEN 'Burial' WHEN 'D' THEN 'D' WHEN 'E' THEN 'E' WHEN 'O' THEN 'O' WHEN 'R' THEN 'R' WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unknown' END AS 'Method of Disposition', COUNT(method_of_disposition) AS Count FROM data GROUP BY current_data_year, method_of_disposition").show()

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/context.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    382         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    383         """
--> 384         return self.sparkSession.sql(sqlQuery)
    385 
    386     @since(1.0)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in sql(self, sqlQuery)
    601         [Row(f1=1, f2=u'row1'), Row(f1=2, f2=u'row2'), Row(f1=3, f2=u'row3')]
    602         """
--> 603         return DataFrame(self._jsparkSession.sql(sqlQuery), self._wrapped)
    604 
    605     @since(2.0)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     71                 raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     72             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: '):
---> 73                 raise ParseException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     74             if s.startswith('org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: '):
     75                 raise StreamingQueryException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)

ParseException: "\nextraneous input ''Method of Disposition'' expecting {<EOF>, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 213)\n\n== SQL ==\nSELECT current_data_year AS Year, CASE method_of_disposition WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cremation' WHEN 'B' THEN 'Burial' WHEN 'D' THEN 'D' WHEN 'E' THEN 'E' WHEN 'O' THEN 'O' WHEN 'R' THEN 'R' WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unknown' END AS 'Method of Disposition', COUNT(method_of_disposition) AS Count FROM data GROUP BY current_data_year, method_of_disposition\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^\n"
```

Sample MYSQL OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: `methods = sqlContext.sql("SELECT current_data_year AS Year, CASE method_of_disposition     WHEN 'C' THEN 'Cremation'     WHEN 'B' THEN 'Burial'     WHEN 'D' THEN 'D'     WHEN 'E' THEN 'E'     WHEN 'O' THEN 'O'     WHEN 'R' THEN 'R'     WHEN 'U' THEN 'Unknown' END AS MethodofDisposition, COUNT(method_of_disposition) AS Count FROM data GROUP BY current_data_year, method_of_disposition").show() `  This line doesn't give that error. All I have done is change the name of case method.

Comment: @user238607 Thank you for pointing this out. Once the .csv file was read in, data schema was all over the place with some random column names. I fixed the error by correcting the schema

Comment: @user238607 Please, see the output above. However, do you have any idea how to go about making plots(any kind) with this output? I'd really appreciate your guidiance. Thank you once more

Comment: I generally use matplotlib for my plotting needs. You can give it a try.

Comment: You can use bokeh in jupyter notebooks : http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/